# How to automatically create a Sentry release and upload source-maps to Sentry in a react project?

Tags: reactjs, bash, create-react-app, source-maps, sentry

I have a create-react-app project, and I'd like the deploy process to generate a Sentry release and upload the source maps to Sentry as well.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This script will create a Sentry release for version specified in the `package.json` file, and upload the source maps to Sentry.

It will work for any JS project, not just React.

create a file in your project root and name it `deploy.sh`:

```
SENTRY_TOKEN="YOUR_TOKEN"
PACKAGE_VERSION=`cat package.json \
  | grep version \
  | head -1 \
  | awk -F: '{ print $2 }' \
  | sed 's/[",]//g' \
  | tr -d '[[:space:]]'`

printf "\nBuilding version $PACKAGE_VERSION...\n\n"

#2) Build for dev and cd to build directory
npm run build # or whatever your build command is
cd build/static/js # or whatever your build folder is

#3) create Sentry release
SOURCE_MAP=`find . -maxdepth 1 -mindepth 1 -name '*.map' | awk '{ gsub("./", "") ; print $0 }'`
printf "\nCreating a Sentry release for version $PACKAGE_VERSION...\n"

curl https://sentry.io/api/0/projects/:sentry_organization_slug/:sentry_project_slug/releases/ \
  -X POST \
  -H "Authorization: Bearer ${SENTRY_TOKEN}" \
  -H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
  -d "{\"version\": \"${PACKAGE_VERSION}\"}" \

#4) Upload a file for the given release
printf "\n\nUploading sourcemap file to Sentry: ${SOURCE_MAP}...\n"
curl "https://sentry.io/api/0/projects/:sentry_organization_slug/:sentry_project_slug/releases/$PACKAGE_VERSION/files/" \
  -X POST \
  -H "Authorization: Bearer ${SENTRY_TOKEN}" \
  -F file=@${SOURCE_MAP} \
  -F name="https://THE_URL_OF_THE_MAIN_JS_FILE/$SOURCE_MAP"

#5) IMPORTANT: Delete the sourcemaps before deploying
rm $SOURCE_MAP

#6) upload to your cloud provider
...
```

replace:

1. `:sentry_organization_slug` and `:sentry_project_slug` with the correct values from sentry (from the URL of any page inside your sentry account website)
2. `SENTRY_TOKEN` with your token from Sentry
3. `THE_URL_OF_THE_MAIN_JS_FILE` with the URL where your react build file is publicly accessible.

run.

Make sure you don't forget to update the package.json version on every release

Comment: How do you run this script? 

Also, Will this script need be run manually before each deploy and will this replace using `npm run build` since this script runs that command already in step 2?

Comment: When I wrote this answer I was using it manually as the build and deploy script. You can also run it in a CLI (e.g. Travis). and yes, it replaces `npm run build` @Badrush

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem recently and despite that there is no official solution for Create React App from Sentry their tooling is great and it's quite easy to automate the process of creating releases by yourself. You would need to generate release name, build the app and use this name to initialize Sentry library, create Sentry Release and upload sourcemaps.

I wrote the article which explains in details how to do it: https://medium.com/@vshab/create-react-app-and-sentry-cde1f15cbaa

Or you can go straight forward and look at example of configured project: https://github.com/vshab/create-react-app-and-sentry-example